# how to populate a combo box with active domains in libvirt using java

Tags: java, arraylist, virtual-machine, jcombobox, libvirt

I am trying to create a list of active virtual machines using libVirt and populate a combo box with them
Unfortunately, something isnt ok

```
public ArrayList<String> getActiveVirtualMachines() throws LibvirtException
{
    int[] vmsOn = connect.listDomains();
    Domain array=null;
    vmsWl.clear();

    System.out.println("List of running vms: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < vmsOn.length; i++) 
    {
        array = connect.domainLookupByID(vmsOn[i]);
        vmsWl.add(array.getName());
    }   

    for (int i = 0; i < vmsWl.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(vmsWl);
    }

    return vmsWl;
}
```

The list looks like this:

List of running vms:

[Ubuntu, testNew2]

[Ubuntu, testNew2]

As opposed to:
List of running vms:

Ubuntu

testNew2

And it is the same story with combo box there are 2 identical entries:

[Ubuntu, testNew2] 
[Ubuntu, testNew2]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you are iterating over the list, you are printing the entire list, not just the particular element you need, so consider replacing

```
for (int i = 0; i < vmsWl.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(vmsWl);
}
```

with

```
for (int i = 0; i < vmsWl.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(vmsWl.get(i));
}
```

or even better:

```
for (String name : vmsWl) {
    System.out.println(name);
}
```